# Get full height of content of tableView

Tags: swift, autolayout, tableview

I'm facing the following issue:

- I have container view which has tableView, tableView contains cells and footer
- in the footer, I have UIView, which contains another tableView with cells (this is opaqued into PageBoy because I've to change tabs due to date of tableView content)

What I want to achieve?

I want to resize tableView footer to fit content of it's tableView.

What I'm doing to achieve this?

I've prepared some research, I've developed ResizableTableView which code is the following:

```
class ResizableTableView: UITableView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        layoutIfNeeded()
        return contentSize
    }
    func reloadData(with completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
        animator.animate(withDuration: 0, options: [], animations:  {
            self.reloadData()
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }, completion: { _ in
            completion()
        })
    }
}
```

And the issue is that on first load view is not resizing correctly - tableView contentSize is not giving me full height, content is cut.

Maybe, anyone has a similar issue with matching height of tableView to its content. I've read a lot of similar questions, but none of them were matching my problem.

I was trying to reload tableView data and then by delegate tell my viewController to resize tableView footer, but this also failed on the first load. Cells are resizing by autolayout - this is probably a crucial problem in this implementation.

Comment: Can you just override the `contentSize` property and call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` in the didSet?

Comment: Rather than depending on `UITableVIew` to provide you the `contentSize` you should calculate the size as you already have information of cell height and number of items.

Comment: This is optimized as you don't need to render the UITableView first just to get the size.

Comment: Probably I cannot calculate size because cells are in different heights. Also, I've tried to call ``` invalidateIntrinscicContentSize() ``` but it also failed to return correct size.

Answer (score 1):

It's not good to contain a new TableView in the footer of your tableView. 
Instead of adding footer view, it'd be better to add new section and use customized cells.

In this way, even you don't have to take care of the cells with dynamic heights of the second section which was the footer of the table view.